# How to remove all decimal points, but retain value In Microsoft Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I need to display with no decimal, but retaining the numbers that
appear after the last decimal. For example, given `03.1037.190

I tried `roundup` and `trunct` but not sure how it works.

Comment: Excel doesn't recognize `03.1037.1903.01` as a number, but text.

Comment: ok but how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on a string where `.` could be on a dynamic spot

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","")))
```

Or when your string always follows the same pattern `##.####.####.##` you could try:

```
=REPLACE(A1,13,1,"")
```

Comment: Why the extra steps? `SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","")))` no need to substitute the `*` just use `""`

Comment: `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","")))` does the same as your formula.  No need to change the last `.` to `*` then find it and replace it with `""`  Just substitute the last `.` with `""` and skip the find and the replace.

Comment: Point proven @ScottCraner, answer edited ;). I was thinking way too complicated there for a second.

Comment: We all do it sometimes.  I have been known to run down the complicated path a time or two.

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite unclear as you have a value with the same thousand and decimal delimiter and also 4 numbers between the delimiters. It would help a lot if you specified the actual number without thousand delimiters.

Assuming there are no decimals (31.037.190.301): remove "." using:

> =SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","")

and Excel will recognize it as a number

Comment: But this is not what OP wants.

Comment: I only want to remove last decimal like this 03.1037.1903.01 as 03.1037.190301

Comment: i want output as 03.1037.190301